What graphs resulting from vertex identifications of a hypercube are equivalent?
Consider a hypercube, with its vertices labeled by integers $1$ to $2^n$, n being the dimension of the hypercube, and two vertices being adjacent if their binary labels differ in exactly one bit. Now consider the graphs derivable from vertex identifications of the hypercube. Clearly the number of such distinct graphs is upper bounded by the Bell number $(2^n)$, but many of these graphs will be equivalent (equivalence here includes isomorphism, but I am also interested in cases where the number of vertices mapped to each vertex in the derived graph match when comparing two graphs), as many of these graphs will be reflections or rotations of each other. How do I calculate the number of distinct graphs derivable from vertex identifications of the hypercube?

You should use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Are you searching for https://oeis.org/A000616?

@caduk I don't think so, though I do see the mention of hypercubes in that sequence. Can you say more about how it's equivalent to my question?

We color the identified vertices with one color and the other vertices with a second color. We want the number of (non necessarily proper) colorings of a hypercube, accounting for symmetry. This is also A(n, 2) of https://oeis.org/A361870. See this image for an illustration of $n=3$ https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Equivalence-Classes-of-two-color-Ising-Colorings-pertinent-to-genetic-regulatory-network_fig4_329049433 (they don't show only once when we an switch the colors, but they are counted twice, for a total of 22)

I see. I'm interested in cases where you can have multiple different identifications, e.g. 1 (2 3) 4 (5 6 7) 8, where things in parentheses are identified. This would seem to require more than two colors, unless I'm mistaken.
